# How do you mock an object in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mocking

I have the following function:

```
signature_request = client.send_signature_request_embedded_with_template(
    client_id = self.CLIENT_ID,
    template_id = self.template_id,
    title = self.title,
    subject = self.email_subject,
    message = self.message,
    signers = self.signers,
    custom_fields = self.custom_fields
    )

signature_id = signature_request.signatures[0].signature_id
```

I cannot for the life of me mock the `signature_id` value in my test. I know that I am properly mocking the correct target because I am successfully mocking another return value from this `signature_request` object. Any help would be highly appreciated!

I have tried the following:

```
send_request_mocked.return_value.signatures.return_value = 
[PropertyMock(signature_id = 'signature_id')]

send_request_mocked.return_value.signatures.return_value = 
[Mock(signature_id = 'signature_id')]

etc.
```

Comment: It should look something like this, assuming your return value is a list of objects.

`signature_request_obj1 = Mock(name=x, place=y)`
`signature_id_obj1 = Mock(signature_id='signature_id')`
`signature_request_obj1.signature_id = signature_id_obj1`


Similary have for all objects in the list, then add all objects to a list and return it